# Jquery - appending a HTML5 template while setting an attriibute?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any easy way to add an HTML 5 template to the body, and at the same time update an attribute? .. In my case I'm trying to update the id attr. The intended output would be to NOT update the id of #myTemplate, but my I add the template to have the div id set to something specific.

```
<body>
<template id='myTemplate'>
   <div>My Div Example </div>
</template>

<script>
   $(function(){
       $("body").append($('#myTemplate').html());
   });
</script>
</body>
```

---> Intended addition after the script runs (in body):

```
<div id="someNewId">My Div Example</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#myTemplate").clone().attr("id", "whatever").appendTo("body")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a jQuery object, edit all the attributes you want, then append it to the body:

```
var html = $('#myTemplate').html(); //or any other way to generate html
var $newContent = $(html);
$newContent.filter('div').attr('id','someNewId');
$('body').append($newContent);
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Copied it, syntax seems correct, div gets added.  Thought the id attribute is still missing.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Since the template tag isn't present in the `html`, the div element is at the first level. `$newContent.attr('id','someNewId')` will do the job, or could use `.filter`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, if you want to go down the `html()` way, and will actually wrap the content inside a `div` as your current code will just input the content of `template` inside the `body` but without the wrapping `div`.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").append($("<div id='myNewId'>").html($('#myTemplate').html()));
});
```